# Automatic Reference Counting Issue - PhoneGap

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cordova

[image]I have tried creating my HelloWorld Application using PhoneGap + Xcode 4.2 by following some steps as explained on below link:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS

But when i'm running my HelloWorld application on Simulator..its giving my **Automatic Reference Counting Issue** error.

[image]

Comment: can you post the full Error message? your screenshot only shows part of the error.

Comment: Is CDVAccelerometer you added to project from some other source?

Comment: @Shivam Please go through the above snapshot...and help...I have disenabled ARC in my Project...Its coming after it...I'm using Xcode 4.2 (which is not giving me any check box for ARC while creating project..Don't know why) and Phone-Gap 2.4

Comment: @VarunMehta Did you ever solve this? I have the same issue in Cordova 2.6.0 and the `CDVCamera.m` file.

Answer (score 3):

This error is coming cause your project CordvaLib is ARC enabled. However, your class CDVAccelerometer isn't ARC enabled. To exclude the file from ARC, use the `-fno-objc-arc` flag

in build phases > compile sources

Comment: Hey Rushi, I have disabled ARC in my project by going disabling "Objective-C ARC flag" under Target-->Build Setting. I have tried your way as well. Now its giving "Semantic issue - Use of undeclared variable at many places--Any clue?"

Comment: @VarunMehta : seems you messed up with some files. When compiler don't get files it gives this error. Wherever you are getting this error just check that files, class or variable exists in your project.

Comment: I did nothing i just created my application from terminal by giving following command and running it:

Navneet:bin hitech$ cd /Users/hitech/Desktop/VARUN_Mac/PhoneGap/phonegap-2.2.0/lib/ios/bin 


Navneet:bin hitech$ ./create ~/Documents/Cordova22/HelloWorld com.tcs.mobility.HelloWorld HelloWorld

Comment: I had a very similar issue in a freshly created project, too. The plugin's `m` file was not listed in *build phases > compile sources*. Adding the file to the sources list manually, and the `-fno-objc-arc` flag to it, did not fix the problem. Was that not the correct way to add the flag?

Answer (score -1):

While creating the new project it asks "use Automatic Reference Counting" with check mark. If you are not using ARC then deselect the check mark.

If you don't want ARC for the only particular class then ProjectSettings -> Build Phases -> Complile Sources -> Compilerflag. click next to your class and set

-fno-objc-arc

Now only the selected class is ARC disabled.

Comment: Please look at my above comment.

Comment: Check the variable which is undeclared. or show me which line of code it is showing undeclared

Comment: In CDVPlugin.m & CDVFileTransfer.m , i'm getting those errors